# CSS - On hover moving image littlebit left, if not hovered then back to original position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying doing it, but it doesn't work. It should move that image left 10px, but it doesn't. That div has `left` css inside it, I think it's because of that. I tried `!important`, but it didn't work.

Here's JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jwbvxhv0/1/

```
$(".seen").bind("webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd animationEnd", function(){
  $(this).removeClass("animated")  
})

$(".seen").hover(function(){
  $(this).addClass("animated");        
})
```

---

```
@-webkit-keyframes example {
  0% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  25% {
    left: 10px ! important;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0px;
  }
}

.seen.animated {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation-name: example;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
}
```

Comment: Do you want it to be positioned exactly 10px on the left, or 10px relative to it's starting point of 366px?

Comment: Exactly 10px to left

Comment: So it basically looks like, if you hover it then "button" comes out a littlebit, and if u unhover then it goes back in

Comment: I tried your fiddle, and it moves to 10px left of the containing div. It does sound like you want it to animate 10px from it's starting position. You need to wrap your image in a positioned DIV, and then animate your image relative to that DIV. So your DIV would be 366px and your image will then go 10px to the left (essentially 376px). More like this: https://jsfiddle.net/qg7wnh1o/

Comment: Do you mean something like that: https://jsfiddle.net/Konrud/jwbvxhv0/3/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `translate` transform for left/right movement as it does not affect any neighbour elements' position. To make the transition smooth, you need to add `transition` on `transform` property for your image.

Update:
If you have a button next to the img, which has higher z-index as you mentioned. You need to apply the same effect to a parent element that contains both - that image and that button.

```css
.moving-left
{
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease;
  transform: translateX(0px);
  width: 100px;
}
.moving-left:hover
{
 transform: translateX(10px);
}

.moving-left button
{
  left: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<div class="moving-left">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100X100" alt="" />
  <button>Button here</button>
</div><!--.moving-left-->
```

Comment: Yep! That's perfect, One more question if I can ask. If ON that picture is a button and I hover the button then it moves both. The button & image with it. I tried adding that class to button, but it didn't worked like that because button has `skew` transform

Comment: @AleksKpur You want to only move the button? or the image only?

Comment: Both, button has z-index. The button is on the image, cuz I didn't had better method for it.. (image has shape), so if I hover it, then button hovers with it

Comment: @AleksKpur I'm really sorry, but I am not getting your point. You said you want to move both, but then you said that if you hover it (img), then button hovers with it. Can you share a link or explain it in some more details please?

Comment: Alright, so you can see: https://jsfiddle.net/jwbvxhv0/4/ 
There's button over the image. If you hover image then it moves, but if u hover button then nothing happens. I tried to do something if you hover the button then button moves and image as well

Comment: @AleksKpur Ok thanks. I got it. Let me update the code in the answer.

Comment: @AleksKpur z-index should be resolvable. As you can see, I have given the button some z-index to show that it still works, if both are within the same parent, because children's z-index is never higher than their parent's.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/bqg80a That "leave" picture overs that button and because of that it doesn't work correctly. I added to button div that z-index: 100000, but still somehow it overs it

Comment: Add `z-index: 99999; position: relative;` to button div. Then also try to set a lower z-index e.g. `z-index: 1;` for the leave picture. If this does't work, try `z-index: 1!important`.

Comment: Yeah, I just found same thing xD

Comment: Thanks for helping me out